# div with `position:fixed`, but stil have same behaviour as with `position:relative`

Tags: css, positioning

When working with `position:fixed;` this is the expected result one would get:

[image]

What I actually want to achive is:

[image]

**as in** this result when working with two `position: relative;` elements

[image]

Don't get me wrong, I know how `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` works and should behave, how I haven't come around how to get both properties for the same div...

One approach wich works, but isn't a satisfying solution is that I put a `position: relative` -div below my fixed element, not allowing the second element moving below the fixed element because it is already taken by the extra div.

[image]

So I have tried to get this *second relative div* working with `:after` **or** `:before` pseudo-elements. This doesn't quite seem to work

```
div:after, div:before { position: relative; }
```

it somehow get's mixed up because the element itself is

```
div { position: fixed }
```

and turning `fixed` and `relative` around obviously also doesn't work because `fixed` will be bound to the `relative` - element.

Any ideas?

And if somebody is wondering why I need to use `fixed` and don't just go with `relative` : it's for scrolling reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use a margin left on the relative div?

http://jsfiddle.net/q3nQr/1/

html

```
<div id="fixed"></div>
<div id="relative"></div>
```

css

```
#fixed { position: fixed; width: 60px; height:100px; background: red;  }

#relative { position: relative; width: 300px;height:1000px; background: green; margin-left:65px; }
```

**UPDATE**

Take a look at the w3 spec for static positioning (just read the first two paragraphs).

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning

> Absolutely positioned elements are removed entirely from the document
>   flow. That means they have no effect at all on their parent element or
>   on the elements that occur after them in the source code. An
>   absolutely positioned element will therefore overlap other content
>   unless you take action to prevent it. Sometimes, of course, this
>   overlap is exactly what you desire, but you should be aware of it, to
>   make sure you are getting the layout you want!
>
> Fixed positioning is really just a specialized form of absolute
>   positioning; elements with fixed positioning are fixed relative to the
>   viewport/browser window rather than the containing element; even if
>   the page is scrolled, they stay in exactly the same position inside
>   the browser window.

This means that elements with fixed or absolute positions do not associate with any other elements in the document, this means they cannot effect the width of another element. If the width of the static element is not known, I think you will need manipulate the DOM with javascript; something as simple as (jquery, not tested):

```
var staticwidth = $("#static").width();
$("#relative").css('margin-left', staticwidth + 'px');
```

Comment: good point! This would be a possible solution, only problem is that I would have to manipulate the margin with javascript if the `#fixed` width varies. With a `relative` behaviour **instead** of the `fixed` + margin behaviour this would fit automatically. My '#relative'-div fills the remaining space.

Comment: updated my answer to address this comment. I am afraid you needing a static element to have an effect on the width of another element, which it can not do (as far as I know).

Comment: thanks for your update! what I tried now is following: `<div id="relative"><div id="fixed"></div></div>` I set #fixed `width: inherit`. on #relative I set and change the `width`. #fixed automatically takes over the same `width` and when I scroll #relative scrolls away but my #fixed stays, which overlays #relative anyway all the time. So I manage to "bind" my divs to each other, which gives me wanted result without javascript :D. thanks anyway, your suggestion was close enough and helped me to come up with this. +1